# Why am i getting TypeError in imageAI?

Tags: python, imageai

I am getting a error while using `imageAI`.
I have tried troubleshooting the `file path` and am sure it is correct, what am I getting wrong?

My OS Ubuntu 18+ and running Python 2+ .
My code is below:

python

```
import os
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection

execution_path = os.getcwd()

custom_path = "/home/tcslab/Desktop/project-test/"

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "yolo.h5"))
detector.loadModel()

# if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(custom_path, "image.jpg")):
#     print(1)

detections = \
    detector.detectObjectsFromImage(extract_detected_objects = True,
                                    input_image=os.path.join(custom_path, "image.jpg"), 
                                    input_type="file", 
                                    output_type="file", 
                                    output_image_path=os.path.join(custom_path, "image.jpg"), 
                                    minimum_percentage_probability=30
                                    )

for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"] , " : ", eachObject["percentage_probability"], " : ", eachObject["box_points"] )
    print("--------------------------------")
```

> The error I am getting:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
> File "test.py", line 16, in module
> detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(extract_detected_objects = True, input_image=os.path.join(custom_path, "image.jpg"), input_type="file", output_type="file", output_image_path=os.path.join(custom_path), minimum_percentage_probability=30)
> File "/home/tcslab/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imageai/Detection/__init__.py", line 544, in detectObjectsFromImage
> "Ensure you specified correct input image, input type, output type and/or output image path ")
> ValueError: Ensure you specified correct input image, input type, output type and/or output image path
> ```

Comment: Probably you can't set the **same** file as `output_image_path` and `input_image`.  [imageai.readthedocs.io](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detection/index.html)

Comment: Nope, even when i use imagenew.jpg i get the same error

Comment: Try `returned_image, detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=”image.jpg”, output_type=”array”, minimum_percentage_probability=30)` to see if the error message changes

Comment: I still get error